# Java Server that accepts GET and POST requests

Tags: java, post, get, request

Basically I'm just trying to create a java application that runs on some port on local host, and will read queries and send responses. I'm not exactly sure where to begin though, I have experience doing this with node.js, but definitely not java.

If anyone knows any sort of tutorial that would cover this, or have any insight it would be helpful because I've tried searching online, and I can't seem to find exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Install [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) for Java EE Developers and follow [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html).
Baically you will need to setup a [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) server and create a [servlet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html) to handle the GET and POST requests.

Answer (score 2):

There are many resources online.

- Read about servlet and JSP. Install Java JDK from [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/)  along with [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2)
- Follow [this](http://cse.csusb.edu/turner/java_web_programming/jsp/) tutorial or [this](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-First-Servlets.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to download Jetty, it's very light and can be run without using up much resources.